# Count occurences of values inside a list stored in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {
     key1: [1, 5, 65, 78, 4],
     key2: [1, 5, 3, 90],
     key3: [1, 5, 785, 908, 65, 3]
 }
```

### Goal to achieve:

I want to count the occurrences of all the single values inside the lists in my whole dictionary. Something like this:

```
count = {
    1:3,
    5:3,
    3:2,
    4:1,
    65:2,
    78:1,
    90:1,
    785:1,
    908:1
}
```

Then, I want to compute the occurrence percentage of every item inside the whole dictionary:

```
percentage = {
       1: 33.3,
       5: 33.3,
       3: 22.2,
       4: 11.1,
       65: 22.2,
       78: 11.1,
       90: 11.1,
       785: 11.1,
       908: 11.1
 }
```

### My code:

I've tried implementing a list in which I store all the values of `dict` to later use a `Counter` to count all the value's occurrences, and at the end I'm trying to compute all the percentages, but I don't know why this doesn't work.

```
all_dictionary_values =[]
for v in dict.values():
    for x in v:
        all_dictionary_values.append(x)
print(len(all_dictionary_values))

count = Counter(all_dictionary_values)
    
percentage = {}
for k,v in count.items():
percentage = {k: (v/len(all_dictionary_values))*100}
```

###### Note:

The total items (without repetitions) inside all the lists (that are the `values` in the key-value  pair in my dictionary are near 300000, so if anyone knows a faster way to make this whole computation, any advice is well accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten three `list`s. You can use [`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count each value and at the end use the length of `dict` for computing the percentage.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

dct = {
     'key1': [1, 5, 65, 78, 4],
     'key2': [1, 5, 3, 90],
     'key3': [1, 5, 785, 908, 65, 3]
 }



dct_cnt = Counter(chain.from_iterable(dct.values())) # list(chain.from_iterable(dct.values())) -> [1, 5, 65, 78, 4, 1, 5, 3, 90, 1, 5, 785, 908, 65, 3]
print(dct_cnt)

# count of keys in the dictionary
len_dct_cnt = len(dct_cnt)

res = {k : round((v/len_dct_cnt)*100, 1) for k,v in dct_cnt.items()}
print(res)
```

Output:

```
# print(dct_cnt)
Counter({1: 3, 5: 3, 65: 2, 3: 2, 78: 1, 4: 1, 90: 1, 785: 1, 908: 1})

# print(res)
{1: 33.3, 5: 33.3, 65: 22.2, 78: 11.1, 4: 11.1, 3: 22.2, 90: 11.1, 785: 11.1, 908: 11.1}
```